# Rbinding Data frames using do.call

Tags: r

This question has cropped up a couple of times in the past but I can't seem to find a specific answer to my problem.

I have a number of data.frames which I want to rbind together but I'm doing something wrong, here's my code,

```
big_df  <- list(
  df1  <- data.frame(A = seq(1:5),
                     B = seq(6:10)),
  df2  <- data.frame(A = seq(11:15),
                     B= seq(16:20)),
  df3  <- data.frame(A = seq(21:25),
                     B = seq(26:30))
  )

bigger_df  <- do.call(rbind,big_df)
```

Inspection of bigger_df didn't bind together the data.frames such that 1:5 is repeated three times in each of the two columns.  Obviously I would like column A to be 1:5 11:15 21:25 whilst for column B I want 6:10 16:20 26:30.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: The problem is that you're using `seq` when you shouldn't. There's nothing wrong with your `do.call(rbind, big_df)` call.

Comment: That's an incorrect call to `seq`.  I once had a devil of a time recognizing and then fixing an obscure error caused by incorrect use of a colon instead of a comma in `seq`.

Comment: 8.1.65 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Oh, bollocks!  Thanks all.  Replacing the colon with a comma returned what I wanted.  Thanks for the link to the R Inferno, too.

Comment: "Oh, bollocks!" is actually an R command too.

Comment: It is misleading to say that this was a typographical error; instead, one piece of code - the colon - was wrongly used in place of another piece of code - the comma.  I didn't mistype again and again a number of colons, they were intentionally placed in the code.  The problem was that my underlying intention was based upon a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the useful comments, I simply replaced colons with commas which gave the answer I wanted.

Here is the amended code,

```
big_df  <- list(
  df1  <- data.frame(A = seq(1,5),
                     B = seq(6,10)),
  df2  <- data.frame(A = seq(11,15),
                     B= seq(16,20)),
  df3  <- data.frame(A = seq(21,25),
                     B = seq(26,30))
)

bigger_df  <- do.call(rbind,big_df)
```

Comment: This would be better if you showed the code with the changes.